How to set my own config file in Apache Airflow
Installed Apache Airflow through docker from this manual and can't set my airflow.cfg file.
In docker-compose.yaml I found comment option that will take host configuration file and I uncommented this.
I set my host path and tried to throw airflow.cfg to config folder. But airflow still takes config from another source and does not take my config.
For example I only want to change this option:
load_example=True to load_example=False
It must not show dags example. But still it does.

Show the docker compose file you are using . Show the config file you are using

As i can see u uncomment this line
    # If you want to use it, outcomment it and replace airflow.cfg with the name of your config file
    AIRFLOW_CONFIG: '/opt/airflow/config/airflow.cfg'
  volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/config:/opt/airflow/config
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins

But you may need to mount this file from your local machine to inside docker in AIRFLOW_CONFIG directory or could just copy (docker cp) local airflow.cfg to this path inside the container.
Make sure that the airflow.cfg file that u want is in the config directory of the same directory that is docker-compose.yaml
OBS: If u want to change load_examples, you could change the variable in docker-compose file
AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'

